# Undefined variable: bucketname (View:

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect up an aws bucket to read the contents of the s3 bucket into a database I have set up the connection and it returns the bucket names but I now want the contents of a particular bucket

here is what I have

```
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Establish connection  with an S3 client.
 $client = S3Client::factory(array(

'key'      => AWS_KEY,
'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_KEY
));

// list owned buckets


 $blist = $client->listBuckets();
 echo "   Buckets belonging to " . $blist['Owner']['ID'] . ":\n";
 foreach ($blist['Buckets'] as $b) {
  echo "{$b['Name']}\t{$b['CreationDate']}\n";
  }

 //view contents

 $o_iter = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
'Bucket' => $bucketname
  ));
 foreach ($o_iter as $o) {
   echo "{$o['Key']}\t{$o['Size']}\t{$o['LastModified']}\n";
  }
```

for reference I got the above from here :

http://docs.dreamobjects.net/s3-examples/php2.html

Comment: Where you defined `$bucketname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `$bucketname` first.

```
$bucketname = 'The bucket you want to list';
$o_iter = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucketname));
```